# ラズベリーパイカメラモジュールの接続について

Tags: raspberry-pi

ラズベリーパイのカメラモジュールを使って画像を撮影したいのですが、ラズパイがカメラを認識せず動作しない状態にあります。いろいろサイトを当たったところ
・カメラのsunnyラベルのところをクリック
・カメラを再接続してみる
・ラズパイを再起動してみる
すべて試しましたが一向に変化がありません。カメラ自体はLEDが点灯しており電源供給はされているようですがそれ以外は動作していません。
どなたか解決法を教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

OSはRaspbianをお使いかと思いますが、一応Raspbianのバージョンをご確認ください。2013-05-25-wheezy-raspbianより古いものでは、カメラモジュールに対応していません。さすがにそこまで古くないと思いますが、最近のものですと、2017-07-05-raspbian-jessie か   2017-08-16-raspbian-stretch でしょうか。

`sudo raspi-config` を実行すると、「Enable Camera」または「Interfacing Options」という選択肢があると思います。そこで、カメラモジュールの有効／無効を切り替えます。

カメラが有効になったら、`raspistill`というコマンドで撮影します。`/opt/vc/bin`にあると思います。`/opt/vc/bin/raspistill -o image.jpg`の様にに使います。コマンドの詳細については検索してください。